# Custom build using Crosswalk

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

Any way to create a different construction for Android using the "Crosswalk"?

The content of "Crosswalk Android webview (ARM)" basically contains what must be substituted in ..\CordovaLib directory to create a compiled app using this version of "WebView".

See the goal here: [Use Crosswalk With Ionic Framework Android Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0I1OjJLVLMo)

This directory, which would replace the files, is apparently in:
..\bld\Debug\platforms\android\CordovaLib.

How would Visual Studio's behavior in the build? 
I do not know whether to overwrite files or the more important thing is that this build would be only for devices below Android 4.4, which would wash to have to get 2 different builds for Android. This would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could find how to use crosswalk with Visual Studio on this thread :
http://www.spritehand.com/2015/01/using-crosswalk-with-visual-studio.html